# How get name of current model this view context is attached to?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

in API , call $this->model will return model'sname but it dont work.

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/view

is api cakephp false ? even $view->modelId dont work, too.

Answer (score 12):

In controller:

```php
$this->modelClass
```

Comment: This is partially true, because if the model is part of a plugin, it will return the name including plugin (eg, `Plugin.Model`). You may need to split the name

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
Inflector::classify( $this->params['controller']);
```

this should change your controller name in to model name. And you can do it of course from view level.

Comment: thsi may not work http://www.blog.zahidur.com/how-to-get-model-name-in-cakephp/ read the comments

Comment: Thats why i use "classify" instead of "singularize". And this solution works fine.
Check the Inflector documentation http://book.cakephp.org/view/1479/Class-methods

Answer (score 3):

yes you can, you need to tell your model to tell its name. so write a function in your model like:

```
    function myname(){
    return $this->name;
}
```

and now your controller can ask your models for their names.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Inflectors](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html) to achive your wanted result:

```
<?php $model = Inflector::camelize(Inflector::singularize($this->params['controller'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's because the view's parent is a controller (which you can't also access), and the controller could have multiple models.

If you are trying to access the Model's name in your View it is very likely you are doing something wrong or simply you haven't understood the MVC design pattern yet.

I can't think of one case which a Model's name is relevant to the view. I insist, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: "I can't think of one case which a Model's name is relevant to the view" - Exploring how cakePHP works?

Comment: I could find it useful if you need to highlight the selected section on a visual menu. Or am I missing something too?

Comment: What about when you need to create a form dynamically in an element?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$view =& ClassRegistry::getObject('view');
$models = $view->params['models'];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are following the CakePHP Conventions and Rules, a model name is the same as a Controller Name but in singular, the Controller name should be plural, so to get the controller name in View, simple add the following:

```
<?php
$controller = $this->name
```

and the model name in view will be:

```
$model = trim($controller , "s");
```

this is the only way to get the model name in view

Comment: Bad idea, look at this example: `Territory` > `Territories`, this will not work with your code.

Comment: @ToniAlmeida is right, use `Inflector::singularize($controller)` instead. This might also have weird results if your controller /starts/ with an "s".